# Define a Scheme /Data model to integrate multiple Data source for our Business case in Neo4Js

Tags: neo4j, nosql, ontology

Dears

We have business use case where we are getting data from different data sources -Relation DB , NoSQL, File feed-(CSV ,JSON)  and we need to aggregate all data and needs to present to a Graph Model and we need to apply some business rule to figure out the rating /Ranking for the entity.The data is related to Pharamcy . Can you please guide me how we can  define a scheme in Neo4Js? Are we able to define a generic scheme so that it will take care of any new data set ?

Any help or direction would be highly appreciated .

Comment: Traditionally, RDF graphs are considered more suitable than LPG graphs for heterogeneous data integration tasks...

Comment: Thanks Kralin. I did research based on your suggestion .I was trying to use AllegroGraph ,do you have any recommendation  RDF Graph? I am completely new to RDF graphs .We need to rank pharmacy based on certain parameter as well

Answer (score 0):

Its all depends on the Use case .

If the data from different data sources are logically related then the better approach will be :

- Use RDF Graph storage  - Blazegraph / Neptune / StartDog
- Generic Schema can be defined using RDFS
- The different Data sources can be logically linked using Ontology Concepts (OWL)
- In this case we can easily incorporate new data sets as it is related
- Can use inferences for analytics use cases

if the data sets has no logical relation then :

- Still RDF graphs will be better approach as it is flexible and  will have wide options

Comment: Thank you Don, can you give reference for ontology based data integration?

Comment: Are you expecting some project reference or Ontology document reference

Comment: Don, I was trying to see how we can do Ontology mapping against data sources and integrate to target graph (the process or steps involved) project reference would be great.

Comment: Below are the two links will help you for the integration: http://www.linkeddatatools.com/introducing-rdfs-owl https://www.obitko.com/tutorials/ontologies-semantic-web/owl-example-with-rdf-graph.html